# Can't find package of GO for GPL6244 in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a gene enrichment analysis. The dataset I'm using is GSE28735, which is built using platform GPL6244.
I got a matrix with differentially expressed genes, and now I want to run a Gene Ontology analysisi.
I have created a rank vector that looks like this:

| ID | B |
| --- | --- |
| 7908072 | 32.54409 |
| 8037408 | 31.95662 |
| ... | ... |

This is the code I'm running:

```
rankgenevector <- 
  sort(rankgenevector,decreasing = TRUE)

ego_gsea_inf_pne <- gseGO(geneList     = rankgenevector,
                          OrgDb        = pd.hugene.1.0.st.v1,
                          keyType = "PROBEID",
                          ont          = "ALL",
                          exponent     = 1,
                          minGSSize    = 10,
                          maxGSSize    = 1000,
                          eps          = 1e-12,
                          pvalueCutoff = 0.05,
                          verbose      = FALSE,
                          pAdjustMethod = "BH",
                          by           = "fgsea")
```

But I get the following error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
> unable to find an inherited method for function ‘species’ for signature ‘"AffyGenePDInfo"’

Any help would be appreciated.